# Span background across two spanning divs, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put two spans in one container to achieve a background that spans across these two spans. I've made a jsfiddle example, see below

http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/1/

The problem is that the div doesn't seem to span across these two, instead it lays on top of the two spans. If I set background to the two spans individually I get the gutter between them, which shouldn't be visible. I've also tried to locate if the divs aren't closed properly but to no avail.

Updated with less junk:
http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/5/

Comment: If your jsfiddle had less "junk" unrelated to the question, it would be much easier to answer.

Comment: @wroniasty sorry about that. updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/5/

Comment: It is because of not clearing. `clearfix` clears your issue! Second fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/7/

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, now the whole width is black. The column where the nav bar resides should not have a black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It is because of not clearing. `clearfix` clears your issue!

Just add a `clearfix` class to the `.bgcolorblack`. If you have menus coming out of the `div`, `overflow: hidden;` will trim them.

```
<div class="bgcolorblack clearfix">
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/6/

Generally TBS comes with `clearfix` class. But if you find it is not included, you can very well copy this to your CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

#### Second fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/7/

In case if you don't need space, give the wrapper a class `span10`. And in the CSS:

```
.bgcolorblack.clearfix.span10 {margin-left: 0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/9/

Comment: Thanks, problem is that the background behind the navbar also gets changed. Only the two columns to the right should have a different background.

Comment: In case if you don't need space, give the wrapper a class `span10`. And in the CSS:

    `.bgcolorblack.clearfix.span10 {margin-left: 0;}`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/9/

Comment: This last example is the closest to what I need, however, somehow there is much unused space in the third column to the right. If I change it to a span5 instead of 4 it looks better, but that makes it an 13span instead of 12 total.

Answer (score 0):

Change the div to have a class of span10 and it works I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/3/

Comment: It kind of works, but the third column to the right gets smaller for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

***[LIve demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/4/)***

add this css

```
.bgcolorblack{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsEWG/4/)***

Comment: This almost works. But somehow the column to the far right gets a smaller width, not as it was before.